# How to join columns in CSV files using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
# data.csv (this line is not there in the file)
Names, Age, Names
John, 5, Jane
Rian, 29, Rath
```

And when I read it through Pandas in Python I get something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(data)
```

And the output of the program is:

```py
  Names   Age  Names
0  John     5   Jane
1  Rian    29   Rath
```

Is there any way to get:

```py
  Names   Age  
0  John     5   
1  Rian    29   
2  Jane
3  Rath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd suggest having unique names for each column.  Either go into the csv file and change the name of a column header or do so in pandas.

Using `'Names2'` as the header of the column with the second occurence of the same column name, try this:

Starting from

```
datalist = [['John', 5, 'Jane'], ['Rian', 29, 'Rath']]
df = pd.DataFrame(datalist, columns=['Names', 'Age', 'Names2'])
```

We have

```
  Names  Age Names
0  John    5  Jane
1  Rian   29  Rath
```

So, use:

```
dff = pd.concat([df['Names'].append(df['Names2'])
                                    .reset_index(drop=True), 
                 df.iloc[:,1]], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
                .fillna('').rename(columns=dict(enumerate(['Names', 'Ages'])))
```

to get your desired result.

From the inside out:
`df.append` combines the columns. 
`pd.concat( ... )` combines the results of `df.append` with the rest of the dataframe.

To discover what the other commands do, I suggest removing them one-by-one and looking at the results.

Please forgive the formating of `dff`.  I'm trying to make everything clear from an educational perspective.
Adjust indents so the code will compile.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
**usecols** which helps to read only selected columns. 
**low_memory** is used so that we Internally process the file in chunks.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols = ['Names','Age'], low_memory = False))
print(data)
```

Please have unique column name in your csv

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem in column 3. None of the columns are called `col1` or `col2`.

Comment: I guess I didn't explained properly. col1 and col2 are the column name. In your case replace col1, col2 with Names, Age respectively in the code. And column name 'Names' is repeated twice in your case, change one of them to have unique column names. I have also updated my answer.